# How to toggle bootstrap collapse from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to toggle bootstrap collapse programmatically which is

```
 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingStores">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <span class="collapsed" id="StoresPanel" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#filter-field-container" href="#filterStores" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="filterStores">
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>  Stores
                                        <span ng-if="showStore" class="pull-right">{{countStore}}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
```

My angular code is

```
    var domElement = document.getElementById('StoresPanel');

    angular.element(domElement).collapse('show');
```

But collapse('show') is not invoking the toggle functionality. Kindly help !

Comment: why are you using `triggerHandler('click')` instead of `ng-click`?

Comment: You've tagged `angular-ui-bootstrap`, did you take a look on it? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse

Comment: Yes I have. But again this is using ng-click, I just want to toggle(show and hide) from angularjs code.

Comment: Angular-ui-bootstrap is a rewrite of bootstrap for angular which is in angular way and also avoids jQuery dependancy. If you use angular-ui then do things angular way or don't use it! Also if your question is not related to angular-ui remove the tag from question.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but, I am using bootstrap's collapse component (not angular ui bootstrap) and wanted to control it from my angular1 controller, then you can do like (jQuery would need to be loaded):

```
 const el = document.querySelector(target);
 if (!angular.element(el).hasClass('in')) { // hidden
     $(el).collapse('show');
 }
```